# Filter data in Dashboards?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In our Dynamics CRM online instance, we've created several dashboards for the monthly performance review. In total we got 24 lists and charts.

Problem: We've got 16 sales-teams/regions. So, when our CEO is meeting with one team, he needs to filter down 24 lists.

We see several solutions:
a) Introduce Power BI: So far we didn't use it we are reluctant to introduce it due to some weaknesses it has.
b) Clone the 24 charts, lists and dashboards. Doing it once would be feasible but afterwards we would have a maintenance nightmare.
c) This is where you come in: Is there a plugin, workaround, script or some other idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom HTML webresource to embed in dashboard, develop with bootstrap & webapi calls to pull the data. Open source js charts, jQuery grids, cool controls to visualize.

My choice is PowerBI because of powerful slice & dice, great visualization & easy to build.

Lot of charts, views, dashboards are going to be maintenance nightmare. Though we have xrmtoolbox for managing certain things.

Comment: Yes, BI looks great, but doesn't allow to click-through to the individual record. Opening an opportunity in Dynamics does not work with PowerBI.

Comment: @Sparhawk you can add a record url column in PBI list & users can click to open the record.

Comment: @Sparhawk is right: the PowerBI Service does have DrillThrough capability - but only on Reports and not on Dashboards.